# If L1L2 regular language then L2L1 regular?

Tags: concatenation, regular-language

I have two languages and I don't know anything except that the concatenation L1L2 is a regular language.
I know that they can be regular/nonregular and it will still apply but what about L2L1?
I couldn't find any example that L2L1 is nonregular and I don't know how to prove that either.
I tried to think about modify the automata but because one of the languages (or both) may be nonregular it makes non sense.
Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

L1L2 is regular and L2L1 is non regular

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32567134)